# Lower bound on convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have a sequence of continuous random variables $X_n$ that converges in probability to $X$. Given any $t$ and $\epsilon$ is it true that
$$P(X \leq t- \epsilon) \leq P(X_n \leq t) +P(|X_n -X| \geq \epsilon)$$
I've constructed some examples and it seems like it should be, but I'm having trouble establishing the bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to prove that$\def\eps{\varepsilon}$
$$ \{X \le t -\eps\} \subseteq \{X_n \le t\} \cup \{|X_n - X| \ge \eps \} $$
Suppose that $X(\omega) \le t- \eps$, if $X_n(\omega) \le t$, we are done, in the case $X_n(\omega) > t$, we have 
$$ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| = X_n(\omega) - X(\omega) > t - (t- \eps) = \eps $$
Now use subadditivity of $\mathbf P$.

Comment: Is it possible to get a bound in the other direction?

Comment: In what direction? @Wintermute

Comment: $P(X \leq t + \epsilon) \geq P(X_n \leq t)+P(|X_n-X|\geq \epsilon)$